# Key error while trying to convert strings into categories

Tags: python

I have two questions in this post:

First:

I am working with the following dataset.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8lbehhqokkasic/bank-full.csv?dl=0

I would like to convert the Job column into categories / number in order to implement algorithm on it. This might be silly question but i am a newbie. Sorry.

Here is my code so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv('bank-full.csv', sep='\s*,\s*',
                           header=0, encoding='ascii', engine='python')

print (df["job"])

df["job"]=df["job"].astype('category')
df["job"]= df["job"].cat.codes
```

But i get the following error.

```
KeyError: 'job'
```

Second:

I am not sure where i am doing mistake. Do i have to define header first? As the data is separated using ; it cannot probably see the column headers. I have tried to define it with next() method but did not work either. It gives the same error

```
KeyError: 'job'
```

[df.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R7Mx.png)

Comment: Can you try printing the value of `df.head()`?

Comment: Post edited.Pls find the image clicking on df.head() which is at the end of the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the value of `df.head()` that you have shared in the image above, it is apparent that the CSV file is not getting parsed as desired. Provide the separator argument with the value of semi-colon like so:

```
sep=';'
```

Refer to [this](http://pythonforengineers.com/introduction-to-pandas/) post if you need more details about parsing CSV files in Pandas that aren't really comma separated.

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm. Also thanks very much for the link. Love to learn python. Links like this will definitely help me.